# AOT Angular Module

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-aot

I've been trying to export a simple Angular4 module to work in another project for at least a month. Read a lot of articles but it's not working.
Here [a file containing two folders](http://ge.tt/15xUMpl2):

```
lib -> Containing a simple Angular4 module
demo -> Containing a simple AngularCli project
```

The `lib` is a very simple implementation of an Angular module, and `demo` is importing that module inside of its root module.

No matter what I do the demo app gives me different kind of errors saying that the `lib` is not an Angular module.
Sometimes talking about not include decorators, and sometimes this error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 194:50 in
>   the original .ts file), resolving symbol NgModule

I tried to target `es5` and `es2015` without any luck.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. download the zip and extract it into a folder
2. cd `lib` folder
3. run `npm install` or `yarn install` to install the dependencies
4. run `npm run bundle` or `yarn bundle` to bundle the library into
   `dist`
5. cd `demo` folder
6. run `npm install` or `yarn install`
7. run `npm install ../lib` or `yarn add file:../lib` to install the local `ng-test-lib` which is inside of `lib` folder
8. run `npm start` or `yarn start` to start the Demo project

### Update:

I add the contents of some of files here:

**lib/src/a-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ADirective } from './a-directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ADirective,
    ],
    exports: [
        ADirective,
    ]
})
export class AModule {}
```

**lib/src/a-directive.ts**

```
import {
    Input,
    OnInit,
    Directive,
 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[aDir]',
})
export class ADirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() test: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(`I'm the directive, and this is test value: ${this.test}`);
    }
}
```

**lib/tsconfig.aot.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "stripInternal": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ],
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "types": []
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/a-module.ts"
    ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "strictMetadataEmit": true,
        "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
        "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
        "flatModuleOutFile": "index.js",
        "flatModuleId": "index",
        "genDir": "./dist"
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Comment: Can you also post the code of your lib module here? Some of us may not be on a machine we can download/run your code.

Comment: Sure. I added some code

Comment: I believe this is an issue related to `@angular/compiler` that's why it requires to compile and see what's going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the issue is symlink-ing the folders meaning if you use `npm install ../lib` the issue won't happen! I didn't try it cause I thought it's the same as `yarn add file:../lib` but no.

At the end this is an issue related to `@angular/compiler` that is not working properly with symlink directories.

That's it.

I hope this helps someone else not to waste their time as much as I did.

**Updates**
Be aware that this issue will happen if you're using npm v5 cause it uses symlink to link local packages.

Comment: was nearly giving up, but this saved it.
had to downgrade npm from 5.x to 4.6.1 then it worked.